# Navigating through multiple pages in an Electron app

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I'm really a beginner when it comes to HTML/JS, and I'm trying to build a simple multi-page app based on Electron. As the layouts and overall functionality of the pages are quite different, I've read that I should avoid the the single-page app approach which is well documented. I want to move from one page to another using buttons and I'm stuck. I'm creating the buttons in the main page, but I'm unable to create additional ones when loading a different page.
So, the Start page is created with 2 buttons, which will open the Page2 and the Start page, but no buttons appear on the new created windows. As I'm reloading the Start page, I was expecting the same 2 buttons to appear. Also, as page2 points to the same script as the Start page, I was expecting to see the 2 buttons appear on page2.

Adding below the code:

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "multiple-windows3",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

**Index.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow,ipcMain } = require('electron')
function createWindow () {
  let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800,height: 600, webPreferences: {
    nodeIntegration: true}
   })
  win.loadFile('index.html')
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
ipcMain.on('open-new-window', (event, fileName) => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width:800, height:600})
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/` + fileName + `.html`)
})
```

**Index.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Start</h1>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Home.js**

```
const remote = require('electron').remote
const main = remote.require('./index.js')
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron');

var button = document.createElement('button')
button.textContent = 'Open Window'
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'page2');
}, false)
document.body.appendChild(button)

var button2 = document.createElement('button')
button2.textContent = 'Open Window2'
button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
    ipcRenderer.send('open-new-window', 'index');
 }, false)
document.body.appendChild(button2)
```

**page2.html**

```
<body>
    <h1>Page2</h1>
    <script src="home.js"></script>
</body>
```

Thanks